# Install Sailfish OS on Lenovo Yoga 13

Tags: linux, laptop

I have two SSDs in my Lenovo Yoga 13 and would like to install Sailfish OS by Jollaon the second SSD next to Windows 8.1.

Is there an x86 installer image?

Answer (score 2):

First of all it is technically possible to use Sailfish at Yoga Lenovo. It is not a question what could be not easy but a question to get in touch with those who have ported sailfish on many kinds of machines, who could help or who has already done it. Sailfsih in fact is Linux MeeGo Sailfish OS, hence it has legacy of MeeGo. MeeGo is combined Mobilin by Intel and Maemo by Nokia. Intel did it as Intel want more OS to use CPUs by Intel. There where Ideapad S100  running natively MeeGo as firmware, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenovo_IdeaPad_S100 . So it is for 100% possible to have Sailfish ported on IdeaPad Yoga also. Sailfish also can run on standard PC. It is only a question to get in touch with somebody who know how to do it, or did it already and want to share with know-how. I would suggest to ask a question via JollaHQ at Twitter or at forum Maemo.org. Well, last but not the least you ought to ask Lenovo, it is possible they can help (if they want), cause S100 and Yoga can have many similarities and also drivers can fits or be the same. Also Sailfish 2.0 on Jolla Tablet use Atom CPU and this kernel could be or used or similar perhaps.

Linux MeeGo Sailfish OS is Linux operating system of general purpose. It has been popularised with mobiles but it is used with pads, tablets, laptops and PC as well. You can find at Youtube plenty of devices runing Sailfish and list of devices which have been running with Sailfish (so ported) at Wikipdia Jolla or Sailfish OS. SO it can be done, just some efforts are needed.

Answer (score 1):

> Sailfish OS can be used on any hardware with a Linux kernel supported by the Mer core distribution.

As per Wikipedia. That being said, the best I could find was a VM of the OS that can run on x86_64 hardware. It is natively built for the ARM architecture and won't typically be able to run on a normal computer (It's meant to be an android replacement on tablets and phones).

My best answer is that running it as a natively booted OS is currently a non-possibility on a standard PC.

Comment: Not the answer I hoped for, maybe someone else has a solution :)

Comment: If you have extensive programming and hardware experience, you could port it to an x86_64 architecture natively. That is really the only other solution... Well, maybe not... You could petition them to port it to other architectures but I'm thinking they will be less than receptive to the idea.

Comment: They actually have a x86 port for the Jolla Tablet, that is the reason, why I hoped it would work on my Yoga aswell

Comment: You'll need to get every driver for your system rewritten to work with which ever kernel version they are using. If it's an unmodified version of the Linux kernel, you might have some luck getting drivers to work. If it's a modified version of the Android Kernel, I can't be of any use but I'd assume drivers would be entirely a no-go. Put in a feature request at their site. You might get lucky.